# Is it possible to run an MSI from an InstallShield Express Custom Action?

Tags: installshield, localdb

I am using InstallShield Express Spring 2012 SP1.  I would like to run the SQLLocalDb_x64.MSI from a custom action.

Is it possible to run an MSI from a custom action in InstallShield Express?

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you cannot run an MSI as a custom action on Install Execute Sequence in another main MSI package. Windows Installer does not allow two MSI packages to run at the same time, so you will get an error message.

The standard approach for launching an MSI conditionally from another MSI is to embed it as a chained package.

Unfortunately I don't use InstallShield Express, so I don't know if it supports chained packages, usually this feature is available in a commercial edition.

Answer (score 1):

I am fully agree with Bogdan, but there is one trick. You can run msi from custom action at the end of your installation after InstallFinalize phase. You could use the following CA:
 `InstallIntStd    226 SystemFolder    msiexec.exe /passive /i "[SOURCEDIR]YourSetup.msi"`

Where:
`InstallIntStd` name of custom action;
`226` Type: An asynchronous execution of EXE without waiting result;
`SystemFolder` Directory where msiexec located;
`msiexec.exe /passive /i "[SOURCEDIR]YourSetup.msi"` Launch string.

Comment: Igor = thanks most kindly - I will give this a try and post the results.

Comment: One important thing to mention for Igor scenario. It will work, but only for a single MSI, i.e. if you have 2 or more MSI packages that you want to install, they will all be launched almost simultaneously, causing the installations to fail.